# How to say if we send something wrong

Tags: word-usage, grammar, sentence-structure

How to say if we send something wrong

" I'm sorry by-mistake I sent to you."

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct for the most part. The only problem is that you forgot to specify that you actually sent SOMETHING. In other words, the verb *to send* requires an object to use it with (these kinds of verbs are called [**transitive verbs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb)). In the case of your example, use the pronoun *it* to refer to the thing that you sent. I also think that the more natural position for the expression *by mistake* would be at the end of the sentence and there should be no hyphen between *by* and *mistake*. Finally, the following is the improved version of your sentence:

> I'm sorry. I sent it to you by mistake.